# Excel Autohide/Unhide rows based on Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I've been assigned a task at work but am rather unfamiliar with VBA code (or coding in general). My goal is to automatically hide/unhide rows based on the value of 2 different cells. I've found the following code that is working but I am struggling to adjust it so it will check the value of cell B13 in addition to B12. I want to ensure someone cannot enter information into cell B13 then accidentally hide it by removing the information from cell B12.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
If Target.Value = "" Then Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = True
If Target.Value <> "" Then Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question.  This code only runs when B12 is changed and hides row 13 if the target value is blank **and** B13 is blank.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
    Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "" And Range("B13") = "")
End If
End Sub
```

If B12 is blank and B13 is changed no code will run but you could change the If statement to

```
If Target.Address = "$B$12"  or Target.Address = "$B$13" Then
```

Then it would run if either cell was changed.

Edit for the comment:

Try (check to make sure I've got the worksheets right):

```
Worksheets("CS Personnel").rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "" And Range("B13") = "")
```

Comment: Now if I wanted to hide the same rows in another sheet called 'CS Personnel' based on the same criteria in the original sheet called 'Personnel', would there be a simple way to add that in? Basically, if 'Personnel' row 13 is hidden, then also hide 'CS Personnel' row 13.

Answer (score 0):

The final code is below and it works great on the sheet it is in as well as the 2 other sheets that I wanted to hide rows in.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
        Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "" And Range("B13") = "")
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
        Worksheets("CS Personnel").Rows("13").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "" And Range("B13") = "")
    End If
    If Target.Address = "$B$12" Then
        Worksheets("Basic Budget").Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "")
    End If
End Sub
```